# IF Excel function - Wildcard alternative in 'logical_test' segment

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm struggling to include a wildcard at an IF function. I am aware that the IF function does not support a Wildcard. I've seen a few posts on SO, which I can't understand why they aren't working with my formula.

Here is my original formula (which works):

```
{=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(SHEET1!D1:D10="Text", SHEET1!D1:D10), SHEET1!D1:D10)>0))}
```

Here is what I'd like to do:

```
{=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(SHEET1!D1:D10="*"&A1&"*", SHEET1!D1:D10), SHEET1!D1:D10)>0))}
```

This would allow me to just modify whatever text is in A1 to get the result that I want in the adjacent cell containing the formula.

I've tried replacing the IF's **logical_test** with `FIND()`, `IFERROR()`, `SEARCH()`, as well as multiple other functions and combinations that I have gathered from other posts, but I fail at getting the result that I want.

Looking forward to receiving some support.

[SHEET1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEpRN.png)

[SHEET2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfJZY.png)

Comment: Could you supply some sample data and expected outcome please?

Comment: You are referring to the same range `D1:D10` in your formula, I am not sure if it can give right results. Just curious, I populated `D1:D10` with value as "Text" and tested your working formula which returns 0.

Comment: @QHarr Here is a sample:

**Sheet 1 (A-Date / B-Operator Initials / C-Task Number)
28/06/2018 AL  1
28/06/2018 AL  2
29/06/2018 JT-F8 1
30/06/2018 GP  1
03/07/2018 GP  1
03/07/2018 JT  1
04/07/2018 GP-DD 1
04/07/2018 AL  1
04/07/2018 JT  1

Sheet 2 (A-Operate Initials / B-Number of days worked)
AL 2
JT 2
GP 2**

Comment: The formula in question helps me find the number of days that an operator has worked (Sheet 2, B Column), as per the sample above.

The formula references in my initial post do not correlate with the sample.
`{=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(SHEET1!B2:B99=A1,SHEET1!A2:A99),SHEET1!A2:A99)>0))}`

Comment: You could try replacing `SHEET1!D1:D10="*"&A1&"*"` with `ISNUMBER(FIND(A1,SHEET1!D1:D10))`. Does this work? Might also just be that you need parenthesis around your `A1`, e.g. `("*"&A1&"*")`

Comment: Thank you @ImaginaryHuman072889, `ISNUMBER(FIND(A1,SHEET1!D1:D10))` is the answer.